# How to control drop down list ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, drop-down-menu

I have loaded names into drop down list and it should be in it, must but problem is that long name extends drop down list horizontally. Any ways to control or make it appear good ?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to trim the words?

Comment: I am picking it from db, it's same as it is here

Comment: So how do you expect to display them? Trimmed?

Comment: by inserting ellipses in middle of text can be useful like this..http://i.stack.imgur.com/CsUoN.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I think this behavior is more a good feature than a bad one.

The display mode depends on the browser. IE9 and older show cutted texts.

All other modern browsers show longer texts when the DDL is opened.

To reduce the space you can cut the text based on characters, but that is not what you want, I think.